# label not updated in kivy it is write on top of the origenal one

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

[image]

Why in my simple code the label text not updating jus overwrite us you see ? see the button text updated but label not

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
#from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_file("update_label.kv")


class MyLayout(Widget):
    def press(self):
        # Create varable for our widget
        name = self.ids.name_input.text
        # update the Label
        self.ids.name_label.text = f'Hello {name}'
        
        self.ids.btn.text = f"Hello {name}"

        self.ids.label.text = f"Hello {name}"

class Update_LabelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()
```

**.kv** file

```
<MyLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
    
        Label:
            id: name_label
            text: "What is your Name?"

        TextInput:
            id: name_input
            multiline: False
            size_hint: (1, .5)

        Button:
            id: btn
            text: "Submit"
            size_hint: (1, .5)
            font_size: 32
            on_press: root.update_label()

        Label:
            id: label
            text: "hi"
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Try to be specific.

Comment: see the labels in the image - the text not updated they are overwrite on the original text - original is (what is your name) but button text updated

Comment: I found no issues (i.e. no overlapping text) with your posted code, make sure `kivy` is installed with all its necessary dependencies.

Comment: Try removing the `Builder.load_file("update_label.kv")` line. That `kv` file will be loaded automatically by kivy, so that line causes it to be loaded twice, which can cause problems.

Comment: thx John Anderson - that's it :)